# How to add a page number on the bottom of the first pages in table of contents, list of figures/tables and bibliography?

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering, templates

How to add a page number on the bootom of the first pages in table of contents, list of figures/tables and bibliography?

```
\tableofcontents
\listoftables
\listoffigures
\bibliography{filename}
```

Preamble:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{mwbk}
\usepackage[tableposition=top]{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{polski}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[cp1250]{inputenc}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{setspace}
\bibliographystyle{asr}
\bibpunct{[}{]}{;}{a}{}{,}
\fussy
\widowpenalty=10000 
\clubpenalty=10000 
\addtolength{\textwidth}{1,5cm}
\addtolength{\hoffset}{0cm}
\addtolength{\textheight}{0cm}
\addtolength{\voffset}{0cm}
```

**EDIT: additional information added previously is not relevant**

Comment: It depends on the documentclass and related packages like `scrpage2`. Whatever it is the best to provide a minimal example.

Comment: @lockstep: I think `page-numbering` isn't the correct tag.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel: Let's just say you'd have to remove `page-numbering` from a *lot*  of questions. ;-) (Perhaps this is a question for `meta`.)

Comment: Thanks @MarcoDaniel -- I added the content of my preamble. In the sty file (not mine) there are more packages and options, but the list is huge, thus i did not put the whole options at first. I do not know what is relevant. There is no scrpage2 in it, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the following to your preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\let\ps@opening\hf@plain
\makeatother
```

Note that this will add page numbers at the bottom of *every* chapter-starting page (including the ToC and the bibliography). Complete example (EDIT: including `natbib` and a `filecontents` environment):

```
\documentclass{mwbk}

\usepackage{natbib}

\makeatletter
\let\ps@opening\hf@plain
\makeatother

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{foo}

Some text \citep{A01}.

\lipsum[1-10]

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

(The filecontents environment is only used to include some external files directly into the example, so that it compiles. It is not necessary for the solution.)

Comment: I do want page numbers in all these situations (pages with titles of every kind). But your solution do not work. Is it possible that there is a conflict with some other options of my document? Regular pages have page number at the top of the page, next to the name of a chapter. For chapters I use: \thispagestyle{plain} and it works.

Comment: Try to add my code snippet immediately before `\begin{document}`. It should also make `\thispagestyle{plain}`for chapter-starting pages superfluous.

Comment: Does not work :/ I will add to the question all packages used in sty file.

Comment: @Karo: Does my complete example work for you? If so, you're doing something different and it is your task to a) reduce your "does not work" example or to b) add things to my example. You also need to sort out your preamble/style file (e.g., don't load `hyperref` twice).

Comment: sorry for the confusion. Your example works alone. But when I put the snippet in the document (also just before \begin{document}) I work on it does not produce the number. I am aware that it is caused by what I have here, but e.g. when I for example do not load hyperref again there is an error: ! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...tnotesep \ignorespaces Źródło: \url 
                                                  {www.unicef.org/ceecis/res...
l.541 ...unicef.org/ceecis/resources_10594.html}.}
                                                  . Przy czym określenie wyj...

Comment: I will try to provide a minimum working example.

Comment: how to add \usepackage{natbib} to the example (when I use the package there is an error: \providecommand\NAT@force@numbers{}\NAT@force@numbers).

Comment: By the way, your tip brought to my attention that I actually excluded style file a while ago, so actually I do not use the other packages. (I made a fool of myself wiht this, sorry :)). But still... I do not know how to add natbib to my example.

Comment: I've revised my example. Note that it still works if I copy and paste your whole preamble *except* `\bibiographystyle{asr}`.

Comment: Thanks lockstep. To work your example need to have \usepackage{polski}, either way I have this ! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> Rozdzia\PlPrIeC 
                           {\l }\ 1\relax .\kern .5em foo
l.1 ...\PlPrIeC {\l }\ 1\relax .\kern .5em foo}{2}
                                                  {chapter.1}. I will try to use your MWE it to provide my example.

Comment: @Karo: But does the error only show up if you add my code snippet?

Comment: Your example works with asr style and produce the numbers. Ok, thanks for help and providing me MWE to fill in (I will try to find out the reasons why in my example it does not work).

Comment: @Karo: Perhaps you should accept my answer to this question and (as soon as you can reproduce the error for your complicated example) ask a follow-up question (with a link to this one).

Comment: The error came when I used your full code, but after I added just  polski package there were no error. Maybe it is concerned with special character in chapter name in mwbk class.   But now it works.

Comment: Lockstep - ok, I will do so, thanks again!