# Follow up: How to add a page number on the bottom of the first pages in table of contents, list of figures/tables and bibliography?

Tags: header-footer

I managed to provide MWE (thanks to @lockstep) for the problem previously described here [How to add a page number on the bottom of the first pages in table of contents, list of figures/tables and bibliography?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38542/how-to-add-a-page-number-on-the-bottom-of-the-first-pages-in-table-of-contents).

The problem is that I am using `\pagestyle{uheadings}`, and it prevent the solution to work.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{mwbk}

\usepackage{polski}
\usepackage{natbib}

\makeatletter      
\let\ps@opening\hf@plain    %it works without adding uheadings
\makeatother

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{uheadings}         %this is what I added.

\tableofcontents

\chapter{foo}
\thispagestyle{plain}         %this is what I added.

Some text \citep{A01}.

\lipsum[1-10]

\bibliographystyle{asr}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

Have you any idea how to include page numbers on the bottom of the first pages in table of contents, list of figures/tables and bibliography while using `uheadings`?.

`\thispagestyle{plain}` works for chapters.

Comment: If this is still the same problem you should edit your original question and state what is not working (yet). It is also OK to de-accept a previously accepted answer if it turns out to not work fully correctly. In this case you should comment to the answerer and state the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to add the redefinition *after* the `\pagestyle` command:

```
\pagestyle{uheadings}
\makeatletter
\let\ps@opening\hf@plain
\makeatother
```